# Email HTML spacing inside table rows and lines inconsistent between outlook and the others

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

Please see the images. One is from Apple mail and one is Outlook. I am interested in making the spaces consistent to match up with the image in the other column. Please see the code below. Any suggestions? Have I made any typos or missed anything? I added the border for a visual test to see what's going on. It's happening without the border anyway.

Some things I tried- moving the styling inside the TD instead of DIV, I tried changing line height to 1. I tried 0 too but that was making everything, well... zero, which I don't want.

Thank you so much!!!

```
<table style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="470">
    <tbody>
                
                                                                                  
            <tr>
                <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <div style="font-weight:400;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:20px;letter-spacing:0.02em;line-height: 20px;">
                        text
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <!--Spacer-->
            <tr>
                <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-moz-hyphens: none;hyphens: none;border-collapse: collapse;line-height:10px;font-size:10px;" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
                                                                                    
                                                                            
            <tr>
                <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse; padding-bottom: 0">
                    <div style="font-weight:700;text-transform:initial;margin-right:30px;font-size:18px; line-height: 18px;">
                        text text text
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                                                                              
            
            <!--Spacer-->
            <tr>
                <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-moz-hyphens: none;hyphens: none;border-collapse: collapse;line-height:7px;font-size:7px;" height="7">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
                                                                                    
            
            <tr>
                <td data-medium-editor-element="true" valign="top" style="-moz-hyphens: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;hyphens: none;text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse">
                    <div style="font-weight:400;text-transform:initial;margin-right:30px;font-size:16px;line-height:24px;letter-spacing:0.02em;">
                                                                                            lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
                                                                                    
            <!--Spacer-->
            <tr>
                <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-moz-hyphens: none;hyphens: none;border-collapse: collapse;line-height:18px;font-size:18px;" height="18">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>                                                                                                


            <!--CTA-->
                <tr>
                    <td class="cta" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <center>
                            <table style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 0; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;padding-bottom: 2px" align="center" >
                                            <div> <a href="#" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;font-size: 18px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color: #000000;padding-top: 10px;text-decoration: none;font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 0.02em; line-height: 18px;" >
                                            Button Text</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                                                
                                        <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" >
                                                                &nbsp; →
                                                                  
                                        </td>
                                                                    
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr height="2" style="height:2px;">
                                        <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;height:2px;font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px;background-color: #00b7b4" align="center" height="2" bgcolor="#00b7b4">&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        
                                        <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;height:2px;font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px" align="center" height="2">&nbsp;                                                                               
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which spaces are inconsistent?

Comment: 1. Above the button
2. around the lorem

Comment: And the whole thing. The top image, you can see extends well below the thumbnail bottom edge.